# TypesScript: Why does keyof {} have the type never?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I am confused by the `keyof` operator when applied to an empty object. Example code:

```
const o = {};
const k : Array<keyof typeof o> = [];
// k has type never[]
```

Why is the type `never`? I thought never is the return type of functions that never return. Should the type not be `any[]` instead?

When changing the object like this, the type makes sense:

```
const o = {a: 1, b: 2};
const k : Array<keyof typeof o> = []; 
// k has the type ("a" | "b")[]
```

I found this behaviour when implementing a function that returns the typed keys of an object:

```
function getKeys(o: object) {
    return Object.keys(o) as Array<keyof typeof o>;
}
```

The function has the return type `never[]` but should actually have `(keyof typeof o)[]` if I am correct

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Ok, so, after the update the questions is clearer to me. The problem here is that you are not using generics, so you are literally asking TS for the keys of *object*, not of *SOME object*.

You can re-arrange the function in this way:

```
function getKeys<O extends {}>(o: O) {
    return Object.keys(o) as Array<keyof O>;
}
```

So that it will accept a *generic* object of type O, and in this case `keyof O` will be typed exactly `Array<keyof O>`. For example:

```
const keys = getKeys({ a: 1, b: 2 });
// Now keys has type ("a" | "b")[]
```

*Old answer before post edit:*

`never` represents a value that can never occur, like explained in the [TS Doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never). This is the case, since there are no keys in the object. To understand it better, this statement from TS Doc may be helpful:

> The never type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type;

This means that, in this case, never is correctly a subtype of string, especially meaning "no string" and so "no key".