# How can I check that an object has at least one record?

Tags: typescript

I have the following TS code:

```js
type FunctionMap = Record<
  string,
  (...params: any) => any
>

function needsARecordOfFunctions(functions: FunctionMap) {
  /* ... */
}

needsARecordOfFunctions({ myFunc: 'foobar' }); // Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(...params: any) => any'.
needsARecordOfFunctions(); // Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
needsARecordOfFunctions({ myFunc: () => {} }); // ✅

// This passes but I want it to fail
needsARecordOfFunctions({});
```

My question is, how can I get `needsARecordOfFunctions({})` to fail with a type error in the above code? I would like to define a record type that, well, has at least one record defined in it.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsEFkCGYoC8UAShEugE4AmAPALABQUUAzsBaggOYA0jzACgB0IsDgo4AtiwBcUHAhABKQgD55ixqsaMAZohQYEUBBAhUWAQVLlqAeV3xkaTCwH7nR2bAMvseFQBvfigAegAqKBEhKHDQxgBfHQZTcysbSioHJ0NXAUCoSRAcuQByXXR0ACNxUqgEpQBuMNCoABVwaFK2Dm461BYTdGB5FhZULgQcKoAbaGB0KFBIKFLhUXEpbwVlNQ0QUqFGVItrMkzs3y8BJpaoAFEAD0gUcygARnkKLjhJCARgCweFAqnARlxhlAAAxHFJmU4ZeyOK55ApFEpQG57QIJeq3UKtQCg5MkCe0ABYDKBiMYQQagkYASSgAHcFCNUCMFlBdDhUDNjvD0uckTk-G4cU0gA)

Comment: Your problem stems from the `{}` being treated not as an empty object in many contexts but as a very wide "anything goes" type. Ensuring that empty objects are disallowed in parameters is tricky. First, you need to make the compiler infer the *exact* type of the argument passed in with a generic type parameter

Comment: Usually, you can then employ the observation that `keyof {}` is `never`, but your case is complicated because of the index signature brought in by the `Record` utility type. You need a utility for removing an index first. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51465182/11407695

Comment: then you can check whether `keyof` of the resulting generic type parameter is `never` or not like this: https://tsplay.dev/Wzyb3m. I will draft an answer later that explains the steps in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to get rid of the index signature as index signature contributes to the shape of the type:

```ts
keyof { [x:string]: any }; // string | number
```

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51956054/11407695) for a generic utility type goes to [Mihail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2115619/mihail-malostanidis), I only adapted it to TS 4.1+. The gist of it is that if `string` is a subtype of `keyof T`, it means that the type has a `string` index signature (check against `number` gets us numeric signature):

```ts
type RemoveIndex<T> = {
  [ P in keyof T as string extends P ? never : number extends P ? never : P ] : T[P]
};
```

Next, you need to make the compiler infer the type of the argument passed to the parameter to process. Therefore you need a generic function signature, in your case with a single parameter constrained to `FunctionMap`.

Finally, you have to ensure the inferred type passes the "no empty objects" constraint. This can be achieved by applying an observation that `keyof {}` is `never` (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61464692/typesscript-why-does-keyof-have-the-type-never) for details). Therefore a conditional `keyof RemoveIndex<T> extends never ? never : T` ensures that such empty object types are not assignable (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62404464/11407695) for a similar example):

```ts
function needsARecordOfFunctions<T extends FunctionMap>(functions: keyof RemoveIndex<T> extends never ? never : T) { /* ... */ }
```

Bringing all of this together:

```ts
needsARecordOfFunctions({ myFunc: 'foobar' }); // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
needsARecordOfFunctions(); // Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
needsARecordOfFunctions({ myFunc: () => {}, func2: () => 42 }); // ✅
needsARecordOfFunctions({}); // error, expected
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=true&ssl=19&ssc=29&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsEFkCGYoC8UAShEugE4AmAPALABQUUAzsBaggOYA0jzACgB0IsDgo4AtiwBcUHAhABKQgD55ixqsaNQkEhEnoAbhACSCKhAAeNACrqiAb35QA2lAAKUTlADWECDoAGZQdvIsrOycXFA2wBCWkd4A-FAIEKYUUHIIcJIARhDZ8YlUyVBpGVk5XlAAurV2bp71jAC%20ANw6DHrQCWyE-oEhUE7u1jJsHNz1cgogUF1QAPQrUTOxAD7p%20UUUPcGIKBgI6RAQ5QCCpOTUAPLB8MhomCz2cdYJSbDHr9h4VQCI4vU6yYZBUKkIymCxWWwOT7fcrnGpVTLFJoqcYrABUUBEQiguPW7R6GUuLBuZEoVEezxObwE40kIAZcgA5MF0OgCuIOUslJ1Vus7OBoBzpjEBahIgh0MAIixUFwEDgCgAbfroKB9KAc6rFDmMCnXW60%20l-MECIUiqAAUWskBQlygAEZ5BQuPlEsAWDwoAU4IquAqoAAGIQmi5mmkPJ5WpkstnHOQ2tRjdoBkFIABMaZUBHUABZc4LhWsoIBQch6lbsAAtZVAxCwWBBIkHFWYoAB3BSK1CK4A64I4VAa6OU6l3OkJ0FJ9pCoA)